# Jquery Datatable - Horizontal scroll in Google Chrome and FireFox

Tags: datatables

I need to use a horizontal scroll in my jquery datatable, than I used the property:

```js
scrollX: true
```

But this just work in Internet Explorer. In Google Chrome and FireFox, it breaks the table on the header and don't show the horizontal scroll (bringing a blank line in own header).

Someone has gone through this problem or know how to solve?

My code:

```js
// DataTable
var tipoAcao = $("#hdn_TipoAcao").val();

var modulo = $("#hdn_Modulo").val();

var form = null;
var formHtml = '';

form = $('#fdsDamIss');
form.remove();

form = $('<fieldset id="fdsDamIss" class="Formulario">').appendTo('div.Conteudo');

formHtml += '<div class="Conteudo">';
formHtml += '<h1 class="Titulo">Lista de DAM-ISS</h1>';
formHtml += '<hr class="SeparadorTitulo" />';
formHtml += '<table id="idTabelaDamIss" class="DataTable table stripe hover row-border order-column">';
formHtml += '   <thead>';
formHtml += '       <tr>';
formHtml += '           <th>DAM</th>';
formHtml += '           <th>Situação</th>';
formHtml += '           <th>Venc. Original</th>';
formHtml += '           <th>Venc. Atualizado</th>';
formHtml += '           <th>Valor Original</th>';
formHtml += '           <th>Valor Atualizado</th>';
//economico
if (modulo == 3) {
    formHtml += '           <th>Tipo ISS</th>';
}
formHtml += '           <th>Ações</th>';
formHtml += '       </tr>';
formHtml += '    </thead>';
formHtml += '  </table>';
formHtml += ' </div>';

$(formHtml).appendTo('#fdsDamIss');
```

```js
var table = $('#idTabelaDamIss').dataTable({
     iDisplayLength: 10,
     lengthMenu: [[5, 10, 20], [5, 10, 20]],
     scrollX: true,
     bFilter: false,
     bAutoWidth: false,
     processing: true,
     serverSide: true,
     ajax: ajax,
     language: {
         processing: "Processando...",
         lengthMenu: "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
         zeroRecords: "Não foram encontrados resultados",
         emptyTable: 'Nenhum registro encontrado',
         info: 'Mostrando de <b>_START_</b> até <b>_END_</b> de um total de <b>_TOTAL_</b> registros',
         infoEmpty: 'Mostrando de <b>0</b> até <b>0</b> de um total de <b>0</b> registros',
         infoFiltered: '(Filtrados de _MAX_ registros)',
         infoPostFix: '',
         paginate: {
             sPrevious: "Anterior",
             sNext: "Próximo"
         },
     }
     , columns:
     [
         {
             mData: "Id",
             sName: "Id",
             width: "7%"
         },
         {
             mData: "SituacaoPagamento.Descricao",
             sName: "SituacaoPagamento.Descricao",
             width: "8%",
             bSort: false,
             bSortable: false
         },
         {
             mData: "VencimentoOriginal",
             sName: "VencimentoOriginal",
             width: "10%",
             render: function (data, type, row) {
                 var ano = data.substring(0, 4);
                 var mes = data.substring(5, 7);
                 var dia = data.substring(10, 8);
                 return dia + "/" + mes + "/" + ano;
             }
         },
         {
             mData: "VencimentoAtualizado",
             sName: "VencimentoAtualizado",
             width: "10%",
             render: function (data, type, row) {
                 var ano = data.substring(0, 4);
                 var mes = data.substring(5, 7);
                 var dia = data.substring(10, 8);
                 return dia + "/" + mes + "/" + ano;
             }
         },
         {
             mData: "ValorOriginal",
             sName: "ValorOriginal",
             width: "10%"
         },
         {
             mData: "ValorTotal",
             sName: "ValorTotal",
             width: "10%"
         }
         , {
             mData: null,
             sName: "Acoes",
             width: "50%",
             bSort: false,
             bSortable: false
         }
     ],
     columnDefs: [
         {
             "targets": -1,
             "data": null,
             "defaultContent": "<a class='VerNotasFiscais' href='#'> Ver Notas </a> <a> | </a> <a class='Cancelar' href='#'>Cancelar</a>"
         },
     ],
     fnServerParams: fnServerParams
 });
```

Comment: please show your code.

Answer (score 0):

> **CAUSE**

See [this discussion on datatables.net](https://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/19089/datatables-bautowidth-false-not-working-when-sscrolly-is-set) regarding this issue.

Issue is in combination of `scrollX` or `scrollY` options and `autoWidth: false` which causes the problem with DataTables implementation of scrolling functionality and column width calculation.

> **SOLUTION**

Add the following code below the datatable initialization function:

```
$(window).resize( function () {
    table.api().columns.adjust();
} );
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zr8m7vra/) for code and demonstration.

For more performance, consider using [debounce function](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) along with the code above as shown in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zr8m7vra/1/).

Comment: I am little bit confused - there is no horizontal scrolling in none of your fiddles?? Is that not what we want by using `scrollX`?

Comment: @davidkonrad, this is http://jsfiddle.net/zr8m7vra/2/ that replicates OP problem. You can see the scrolling if you reduce output window width.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com, didn't work yet, the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have forgot to give the table a fixed width it can scroll within :

```css
div.dataTables_wrapper {
   width: 400px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

at least it works for me -> **http://jsfiddle.net/enbmqyoq/**